# How to use OS X Terminal and a USB cable with a Pi Zero?

Tags: usb, headless, pi-zero, macos

I want to be able to use Terminal on my OS X machine to connect to my Zero directly over USB. How can I do this?

Comment: This is only possible with the Zero and (perhaps, I'm not sure, and there may be some challenges) an A/A+.  The other models have master host controllers only.  USB is not a symmetrical relationship, which is why you cannot connect your laptop to your desktop this way -- in fact, doing so with a normal USB cable may cause permanent physical damage to either or both.  The Zero does have a slave controller and can be used this way.

Comment: Rather than close this as a duplicate, I have edited it to focus on the case where there is a potential answer besides "No".   Note I believe this does require a form of IP networking, but (obviously enough) it is not ethernet.

Comment: See https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/#programming-pi-zero-usb Not having a Zero or A+ I haven't tried this myself.

Comment: @goldilocks: So, assuming I have a Zero, a USB cable, and a Mac, and all I want to do is code or interact using Terminal, how do I proceed (the linked video seems to cover much more than I'm looking for)?

Comment: I don't have an answer, I just know there is one.  Judging by comments on the post linked by Milliways, the necessary features are available in the stock kernel, but you need to use a device tree overlay or two to enable them.  I've had a zero for about 3 days and haven't had much motive to try this myself.

Comment: @goldilocks: FWIW, I'm not married to Raspberry Pi. My scenario is that I'm looking for small cheap Unix computers that I can operate wholly over Terminal via a direct connection from my Mac. RP is nice since it has Python already, but if connecting is a pain, I'm not averse to CHIP or Arduino, or whatever.

Comment: @goldilocks: I agree. It seems like there's a way to do this. I'm not sure what "a device tree overlay or two" is. (I'm entirely new to this.)

Comment: There are no Arduinos that are anywhere close to being UNIX based.  There are many options to the Pi this way although IMO it is one of the better ones.  However, I think it would be a better option to use a beefier model (2/3 -- although these probably then require external power as well) and an ethernet cable.  If basic networking seems too complex a hassle to you, then TBH I am not sure what or why you want to do something with a "UNIX based" system.

Comment: Put another way, you may want to ultimately consider an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378) here.  If you really need a UNIX system to play with, e.g., for school, then like I said, you really need to ditch the ethernet phobia now (also: being POSIX compliant I believe OSX already fulfills the criteria of being "UNIX based", so you may not need anything).  If there is some other more particular purpose you have in mind, then you need to figure out and/or think about and/or explain that.

Comment: @goldilocks: I should clarify the networking issue: I can use direct Ethernet, just not wifi. So maybe a beefier model Pi with a direct Ethernet connection is the way to go. Is that a possibility? (The problem there, it seems, is that I'll need separate power, which is a pain, but doable. And that for a MacBook I'll need to mess with some extra cable adapters.)

Comment: They don't include ethernet jacks on Macbooks anymore?  I think I have noticed this recently but I'll keep my opinion of Apple to myself, lol.   If you have a USB port that promises at least 1 A for charging you might be able to get away using a B+, a Zero should be fine, quad core models will be more of a gamble.  I've noticed that even using a fairly beefy, 20+ Ah, 5V 2 A output power bank with a Pi 3 is sketchy, although I've haven't tried that enough to say how much.  In other words, making the Pi portable power wise is not as simple as it might seem (but that is a separate question).

Comment: I believe the issue with power banks is that while they may be capable of providing the necessary maximum amperage, they do not respond well to sudden and frequent fluctuations in current draw.

Comment: @goldilocks: So it sounds like best way to be most flexible (have access to the widest range of Pi models) is to assume an external power source and make the programming/console connection independently. And the best way to do that sounds (for my purposes) like direct Ethernet. So what I need is the path from a Pi out of the box, plus a Mac and the necessary cables (no keyboard or screen for the Pi!) to direct Ethernet connection via a terminal or (probably better?) SSH.

Comment: Direct ethernet is fairly simple and fast enough for anything the Pi is likely to be capable of doing; you can certainly program via `ssh` that way although most people do that kind of thing as much as possible on the remote machine (e.g., by mounting a remote filesystem, editing/composing using software on the laptop, then compiling or testing via ssh; some IDE's may be able to do this transparently).  For actually setting up the Pi initially I recommend using a screen and keyboard although it is not impossible to do without that if you literally do not have such.

Comment: You can also use [VNC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing) via a network connection if that appeals to you.

Comment: @goldilocks: To be clear (I'm not sure I explained the SSH approach I was thinking of), I have some experience using cloud instances via SSH, and I just want to treat my Pis as instances that happen to be sitting on my desk plugged into my MacBook (or on my network if in cases where I can in fact use wifi). Coming from that perspective it seems silly that I'd *ever* need a keyboard and a screen. This seems like it ought to be a very common scenario, but everything I've found is way complex and/or involves keyboards and monitors. Is there a reference (step by step for beginner) you'd recommend?

Comment: I have piles of HDMI displays and USB keyboards around, so I have never bothered starting from scratch headless although I mostly use them that way afterward. But again, it is not impossible and if you look around (including here) you'll find plenty of discussion about it. If I were to do this, TBH I'd just set-up stuff on the SD card using a normal computer first, but this requires 1) A system that can access an ext4 filesystem, 2) Probably an above average understanding of linux, etc.  This is why I think if at all possible neophytes should avoid trying to do the installation headless.

Comment: In case there is any confusion, using a keyboard and screen to do some initial configuration does not mean setting up a GUI system, etc.  While the process is presumably automated, keep in mind that *something* had to be done to arrange those cloud instances before you accessed them.   **However**, in theory you should be able to take Raspbian out of the box, plug the Pi directly into another computer with an ethernet cable, and *presuming that computer will provide DHCP service* (I think this should be easy on OSX), access it right away via `ssh`.

Comment: [This](https://retosteffen.ch/2016/03/install-raspberry-pi-headless-os-x/) looks very promising (for a Pi 3 Model B).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow [this guide](http://pi.gbaman.info/?p=699). The only things you need are a pi zero, standard usb cable, and a mac/pc. I tested the quick way on both my mac and a windows pc. On a mac i use the OSX terminal to ssh into the pi zero, and i can enable internet sharing for the zero (done in the mac settings). On the windows pc i had to install bonjour. Works great!

Comment: Note that for simple direct USB connection as Ethernet, all that's necessary is [this](https://gist.github.com/gbaman/975e2db164b3ca2b51ae11e45e8fd40a).